# Is there anything wrong with this double ternary?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there anything wrong with using double ternary operator like so:

```
var stateName:String = state is String ? state as String : "name" in state ? state.name : null;
```

Here is two lines because someone requested it:

```
var stateName:String = state is String ? state as String : 
                        "name" in state ? state.name : 
                            null;
```

Here is the alternative:

```
if (state is String) {
    stateName = state as String;
}
else if ("name" in state) {
    stateName = state.name;
}
else {
    stateName = null;
}
```

The function:

```
/**
 * Sets the style in the state specified. Creates state if it doesn't exist.
 * */
public static function setStyleInState(styleName:String, value:*, state:*, target:UIComponent = null):void {
    var stateName:String = state is String ? state as String : "name" in state ? state.name : null;

    if (!StateUtils.hasState(target, state)) {
        state = createState(stateName, null, target);
    }
    else if (!(state is State)) {
        state = getState(target, stateName);
    }

    // more code to write
}
```

It makes sense to me but I'm the one writing it.

This is ActionScript3 or ECMAScript 4 (basically JavaScript with strong typing).

Comment: Except for making your code hard to read?

Comment: The only thing wrong with your double ternary is that you're writing a double ternary. Less LOC != better readability. Always pretend that you're writing code for an axe murderer who knows where you live. Also, given the javascript comparison, [in javascript we never use single line block statements](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#16.1).

Comment: It's also a very long line. Is there any reason you can't just make it two lines?

Comment: @superbiasedman I added alternative versions.

Comment: This actually seems to be an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? This is almost certainly a code smell.

Comment: No it smells pretty good. But I have stuffy nose. It's part of a function that accepts any type type. I'll add it.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I much prefer the verbose one. I haven't used AS in a long time but it reads as perfectly clear now what each does.

Comment: I think the extraction of your name should be an entirely separate function and not a one liner. I'm not versed in AS, but I hear it's pretty similar to JS. Here's my attempt. https://gist.github.com/danpantry/0571ab3b6663e64fdff6

Comment: as @DanPantry pointed out, I was just writing that. Just make a new function where you receive the state and return the desired string and make a call to it. Redirecting responsibility. The better side of it is that it won't matter how you do that function now, in 6 months if you need to read it, you'll have the feeling if it's best to use extensive mode or ternary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your example I think that your double ternary operation should actually be a separate function. When you start getting complex one-liners like this, it is a sign that you need another function. Here's how I approached it:

```
function getStateName(state) {
  if(state is String) {
    return state as String;
  }

  // This will always return "null" if state.name does not exist.
  // I don't know about AS, but in JavaScript if something doesn't
  // exist it returns as undefined (not null), but you want the null
  // return. As far as I am aware, AS supports the || short-circuit and
  // truthy/falsey equivalence, like JavaScript.
  return state.name || null;
}
```

This could be used in your function like so;

```
public static function setStyleInState(styleName:String, value:*, state:*, target:UIComponent = null):void {
    var stateName:String = getStateName(state);

    if (!StateUtils.hasState(target, state)) {
        state = createState(stateName, null, target);
    }
    else if (!(state is State)) {
        state = getState(target, stateName);
    }
}
```

There's more to be said here; I think that exposing mutability like this on a static method (instead of on the instance of a state) is going to lead you into trouble later on down the road and you should probably re-evaluate your design.

Specifically, **state** in static methods is **always** a recipe for disaster when it comes to testability and debugging, especially when you branch into multiple threads.

Comment: The original design has all the state functionality on the base class. It became so huge that I thought about using composition over inheritance just to slim it down. I may merge it back in but the base class is already pretty huge. This is my attempt at moving some functionality out of it.

Comment: Composition over inheritance isn't a silver bullet and you need to think about it carefully. The idea with composition over inheritance is you have small, self contained components that encapsulate their own state.. static methods destroy that encapsulation. It's a noble goal, but I think you are applying it incorrectly. You could consider posting a separate review and we might be able to help you with that?

Comment: I don't have any code to review yet. Well I do have the rest of this class. I could try and write up what I plan to do.

Comment: Here is my initial class. I don't like half the functions but I don't know why. https://gist.github.com/monkeypunch3/fd11109c88f282adf83d I can post a new question if I need to.